# Impossible to use gremlin in OrientDB Studio

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, orientdb3.0

I've been trying to use gremlin with OrientDB (V 3.0.30) using the "studio" provided with OrientDB, but each time I try to run a gremlin query such as `g.V` I get the error: `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityException: Language 'gremlin' is not allowed to be executed DB name="demodb"`.  
I am using a brand new installation (on windows) and I do have a version that comes with tp3.  
I tried creating new databases, each time setting them as graph databases and I tried adding gremlin to the `orientdb-server-config.xlm` as an allowed language for the server side script interpreter but nothing changed.  
What settings should I change to enable gremlin code to be executed from this "studio"?  
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the release note of 3.0.28

IMPORTANT: In this release, for security reasons, remote scripting was disabled by default (apart from SQL, that is still enabled by default of course). This impacts execution like following

db.execute("gremlin", "");

To re-enable remote scripting, you have to edit your orientdb-server-config.xml, adding the scripting languages you need to OServerSideScriptInterpreter:

```
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OServerSideScriptInterpreter">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
            <parameter value="SQL,GREMLIN" name="allowedLanguages"/>
        </parameters>
    </handler>
```

Link to release note:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/OrientDB-3.0-Release-Notes#3028---5-february-2020

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried to do but I typed gremlin in lowercase and with a space before it.